In my java calculator program user is prompted to choose operands in an if statement, however the if statement is skipped
when I run the code the if statements and the choice scanner are skipped. how do I fix this?
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the worlds best calulator");
    // Prompt the user to enter the first integer
    System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
    int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

    // Prompt the user to enter the second integer
    System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
    int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("choose fromm these 4 options(+,-,/,*): ");
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();


    if (choice.equals("+")) {
      result = Calculator.add(num1, num2);
      System.out.println("the answer is: " + result);
    } else if (choice.equals("-")) {
      result = Calculator.Sub(num1, num2);
    } else if (choice.equals("*")) {
      result = Calculator.multiply(num1, num2);
    }
    if (choice.equals("/")) {
      result = Calculator.divide(num1, num2);
    } else {
      System.out.println("invalid operand please try again");
    }
    // Close the scanner
    scanner.close();
  }
}

public class Calculator {

  public static int Sub(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
  }

  public static int multiply(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
  }

  public static int divide(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed.");
      return 0;
    }
    return num1 / num2;
  }

  public static int add(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}

I was expecting after the first 2 integers were prompted by user the program would then ask for an operand to use then calculate once it goes over the if statement. But it just skips it and I'm confused.

Use a debugger to go through this line by line.

the debugger has no errors but returns
"Welcome to the worlds best calulator
Enter the first integer: 10
Enter the second integer: 10
choose fromm these 4 options(+,-,/,*): invalid operand please try again"

Please check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

The question is not whether the debugger is showing an error, but if you watch the values of your variables change as you go line by line, you will see what doesn't work. That's going to work better in the long run than asking the Internet.

This requires an understanding of the operation principle of the 'Scanner'.
'nextInt()' recognizes numbers in the console window and determines them as the following numbers by flipping and breaking lines.
'nextLine()' determines the line break to be the following string.
You assume that the input will be as follows.
1 (enter) -> num1
2 (enter) -> num2
operators (enter) -> choice

But in reality, this is how it's perceived.
1 (enter) -> num1
2 -> num2 (enter) -> choice

If you type 2 and enter, num2 becomes 2 so that the console's input disappears and the empty string enters 'choice' through enter.
To solve the problem simply, modify the code as follows
    // Prompt the user to enter the second integer
    System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
    int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("choose fromm these 4 options(+,-,/,*): ");
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();

